# Code Signing "No account for team" message when signing for different developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcode9, provisioning-profile

I’ve been working on an app for a client using my own Apple Developer account so far while waiting for them to register a Developer account themselves.

They have done this— and the time has come for them to be able to build and run the project on their machine, but they’re getting this error:

`Code Signing Error: No account for team "59xxxxxxxx". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.
Code Signing Error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "59xxxxxxxx" with a private key was found.`

The team ID in the error message is mine, what I’ve been using to build the project on my computers.

Their account has already been set in their Xcode's preferences pane, and I have been added as a member to that team.

I have worked on other projects with other developers where we could build the project simply by selecting our respective Team in the drop-down menu within the Signing section of the General project settings. For some reason when my client selects their team and tries to build the project it still produces this error.

Does anyone know what we're doing wrong?

Comment: having the same issue, how it was resolved?

Comment: @moshebeeri Basically it was client error — they didn't select their Team properly in the drop-down menu for the correct target. Once they did this everything built fine.

Comment: THANKS, We are developing with the React Native framework, I could not find the issue but I realized the team id in the message was not of my account, I just `find replace all` with the right one and it works.

Comment: As of Xcode 14.2 the 'Preferences' pane is now the 'Settings' pane under the Xcode menu at the top of the page.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For me the solution was to set the team in both General settings AND Build settings.

I'm using xcode 9.

Comment: I am unable to find team preferences on General and Build settings in xcode 9.4 . can you please elaborate

Comment: It worked for me! Build settings > Signing > Development Team > type name of development team manually.

Comment: note to myself. for xcode 10, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424462/xcode-10-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found - TLDR: using legacy build system was one workaround that worked

Comment: This worked for me, in Xcode 10.1. To find where the additional team info is needed, I searched using the ID in the "No account for team "2X94RM7457"" message. There were three places, all in Build Settings, under Development Team, such as WatchOS and WatchExtension.

Comment: Yeah, using Xcode 13.3, I had to search for the team in the "No account for team "59xxxxxxxx"" message. Just changing it under the "Signing & Capabilities" tab wasn't enough. It was used to sign the framework, sign the tests, etc.

Answer (score 65):

The solution for me was to set the team in General settings of the target and in General settings of the Tests.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the error was caused by obsolete team ID in the project settings. I.e. I got a project from a person long gone. So, I just copied the team ID from error message and used a search within the project in XCode to find where this team ID is. It found me two places in the project settings, I put a new developer id there and the error was gone.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Xcode 13, select the project and go to `Signing and Capabilities`-tab, there you can change the `Team` and `Bundle Identifier`:

[image]

Comment: Plus one for including a screenshot of how to actually find that tab.

Answer (score 3):

using xcode 10 here ... my appleID wasnt signed in, so i rectified that via preferences > accounts > re-entering my password.

BUT, that still didnt work even after cleaning and restarting xcode.

i finally resolved this by doing file > workspace settings > build system ... and choosing "Legacy Build System" from the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there was a bit of "broken telephone" going on with me and my client and we managed to solve this issue simply by selecting their team in the Signing section of the General tab in the project settings.

Answer (score 2):

Another fix I found (Xcode 11)
Select your project root: go to the 'signing & capabilities' sub-window, and for the field 'team' your team will shown as red because not found, and reset this field.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 11 and having already suceeded to build and archive my project before (having my account settings and build settings already well configured with theire keys and certificates), I fixed it on my side with 'Product > Clean Build Folder' and then re-launched a build (doesn't work everytime unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Just like anything with macOS, a restart did it for me

Answer (score 0):

1-re-login into your account in xcode

2-restart mac

3-Uncheck Auto manage sign

4-Re-check Auto manage sign

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because the account expired (it needs an annual fee). If this is a possibility for you, be sure to double-check that with the account owner.